# Configurable Option Value not showing

Tags: magento2

[image]
It is showing like this. option value not showing in configurable product.

Comment: Add screenshot of back end attribute where you've added value and configurations

Comment: https://prnt.sc/lxrgq1 , https://prnt.sc/lxrgrq

Comment: Add color or image to Swatches.

Comment: @priya, which version of magento you are using?

Comment: Magento 2.2.7 version. i didnt customize anything.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using visual swatch Use **Text Swatch**.

Than add Text whatever you want to show at frontend.

Also if you are using color attribute than you can use **Visual Swatch**.

In Order to use **visual swatch** you must add **color** OR **Image file** to to attribute to display it at frontend.

Comment: And its look like this: https://prnt.sc/lxrlgy

Comment: Its default magento2 . It needs to display right !! but it is not displaying.